# Macro to save only the active worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, save-as

In the below code it saves the complete workbook. I want to save only the active worksheet.

```
Sub sbVBS_To_SAVE_ActiveWorkbook()
ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Comment: You can export the active sheet to a new workbook and save it there but you cannot save one worksheet out of several in a single workbook.

Comment: Thank you for your replying @Jeeped

Comment: So I have to save all the sheets in different workbook.

Comment: yes, it is easy to create a new workbook with a copy of one of the worksheets from the current workbook.

Comment: `Sub SaveAsMacro()

    Dim strDir As String

    'Show standard save as dialogue box
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
        If .Show = -1 Then
            strDir = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End With

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=strDir
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub`

Comment: This code is also saving the complete workbook. It's just making a duplicate one

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Copying a worksheet to no location automatically creates a new workbook in the foreground with a copy of the worksheet as the only worksheet in the new workbook.

```
Sub test()
    worksheets("sheet3").copy
    'there is now a new active workbook
    with activeworkbook
        'save it
        .SaveAs Filename:="some file path and filename without extension", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
        'optionally close it
        .close savechanges:=false
    end with
End Sub
```

Comment: `Sub test()

Worksheets("Sheet1").Copy

With ActiveWorkbook
   
    .SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\my_name\Documents\Excel\test", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    
    .Close savechanges:=False

End Sub

`

Comment: You are missing the End With I had in the code above.

Comment: i have added `End with` now and it's showing expected end sub

Comment: great job. Thanks for the help